# Deleting rows based on multiple conditions in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, boolean-logic

I want to delete rows when a few conditions are met:

An example dataframe is shown below:

```
        one       two     three      four
0 -0.225730 -1.376075  0.187749  0.763307
1  0.031392  0.752496 -1.504769 -1.247581
2 -0.442992 -0.323782 -0.710859 -0.502574
3 -0.948055 -0.224910 -1.337001  3.328741
4  1.879985 -0.968238  1.229118 -1.044477
5  0.440025 -0.809856 -0.336522  0.787792
6  1.499040  0.195022  0.387194  0.952725
7 -0.923592 -1.394025 -0.623201 -0.738013
8 -1.775043 -1.279997  0.194206 -1.176260
9 -0.602815  1.183396 -2.712422 -0.377118
```

I want to delete rows based on the conditions that:

*Row with value of col 'one', 'two', **or** 'three' greater than 0; **and** value of col 'four' less than 0 should be deleted.*

Then I tried to implement as follows:

```py
df = df[df.one > 0 or df.two > 0 or df.three > 0 and df.four < 1]
```

However, it results in a error message as follows:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Could someone help me on how to delete based on multiple conditions?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[For reasons that aren't 100% clear to me](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/gotchas.html#bitwise-boolean), `pandas` plays nice with the bitwise logical operators `|` and `&`, but not the boolean ones `or` and `and`.

Try this instead:

```
df = df[(df.one > 0) | (df.two > 0) | (df.three > 0) & (df.four < 1)]
```

Comment: You want `df = df[((df.one > 0) | (df.two > 0) | (df.three > 0)) & (df.four < 1)]` as to why it's because it's ambiguous to compare arrays as there are potentially multiple matches see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous

Comment: Oh, whoops, didn't see the `and` at the end.  Edited.

Comment: @Brionius: it's basically because `or` and `and` can't have their behaviour customized by a class.  They do what they do based on the result of bool(the_object), and that's it.

Comment: To delete, say, any row with a string that contains 1 of 20 possible subkeys, [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31663495/3491991)

Answer (score 0):

##### `drop` could be used to drop rows

The most obvious way is to constructing a boolean mask given the condition, filter the index by it to get an array of indices to drop and drop these indices using `drop()`. If the condition is:

> Row with value of col 'one', 'two', **or** 'three' greater than 0; **and** value of col 'four' less than 0 should be deleted.

then the following works.

```py
msk = (df['one'].gt(0) | df['two'].gt(0) | df['three'].gt(0)) & df['four'].lt(0)
idx_to_drop = df.index[msk]
df1 = df.drop(idx_to_drop)
```

The first part of the condition, i.e. `col 'one', 'two', or 'three' greater than 0` can be written a little concisely with `.any(axis=1)`:

```py
msk = df[['one', 'two', 'three']].gt(0).any(axis=1) & df['four'].lt(0)
```

---

##### Keep the complement of the rows to drop

Deleting/removing/dropping rows is the inverse of **keeping rows**. So another way to do this task is to negate (`~`) the boolean mask for dropping rows and filter the dataframe by it.

```py
msk = df[['one', 'two', 'three']].gt(0).any(axis=1) & df['four'].lt(0)
df1 = df[~msk]
```

##### `query()` the rows to keep

`pd.DataFrame.query()` is a pretty readable API for filtering rows to keep. It also "understands" `and`/`or` etc. So the following works.

```py
# negate the condition to drop
df1 = df.query("not ((one > 0 or two > 0 or three > 0) and four < 0)")

# the same condition transformed using de Morgan's laws
df1 = df.query("one <= 0 and two <= 0 and three <= 0 or four >= 0")
```

All of the above perform the following transformation:

[image: result]