# Drop rows from Pandas data frame by matching a substring list

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, pattern-matching

I have a list of strings as follows:

```
drop_list = [ "www.stackoverflow", "www.youtube."]
```

I have a Pandas data frame `df` with a column, say with name `column_name1`, which may or may not contain substrings from the drop_list. Sample df is as follows:

```
columnname1
------------
https://stackoverflow.com/python-pandas-drop-rows-string-match-from-list
https://stackoverflow.com/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-column-value
https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstart.html#create-a-textblob
https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/
https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/stackoverflow
https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sHkjdkjsk
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jksjdkjklI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jkjskjkjkjkw
```

So, I want to drop all the rows from df, which contains the substring from `drop_list`.

If I have understood correctly, if the drop_list is the exact value that I want to match, I could have used the following code as per this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663426/python-pandas-drop-rows-from-data-frame-on-string-match-from-list) question.

```
df[~df['column_name1'].isin(to_drop)]
```

Or using `str.contains` method as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679930/how-to-drop-rows-from-pandas-data-frame-that-contains-a-particular-string-in-a-p) answer, if it is just one value

```
df[~df['column_name1'].str.contains("XYZ")]
```

Now, how to combine both the approaches to drop the column?The desired output would be to **drop any rows containing *stackoverflow* or *youtube*** from my data frame:

```
columnname1
------------
https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstart.html#create-a-textblob
https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/
https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/stackoverflow
https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/youtube
```

If I run `df = df[~df['col1'].str.contains('|'.join(to_drop))]` with the the `to_drop` as it is, it retains the the stackoverflow urls, but deletes youtube urls.

If I change my list to more generic as follows
to_drop = ["stackoverflow", "youtube"]

it deletes

```
https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/stackoverflow
https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/youtube
```

So, all I am trying to do is to delete all rows containing stackoverflow and youtube urls. I am avoiding the use of urlparse library!

[Here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/anonymous/74618ab59d2ab6f08a4dfa391894d50b) is a MWE.

Comment: Please provide a sample data set and desired data set

Comment: `.str.contains('|'.join(to_drop))` can be used to check against all elements in `to_drop`  but I am not sure if that's what you are asking. A sample would be good in my opinion as well.

Comment: Added sample dataset. ```.str.contains('|'.join(to_drop))``` will not solve I believe.

Comment: @kingmakerking, why do you believe `.str.contains('|'.join(to_drop))` - will not solve the problem?

Comment: @MaxU because it will try to match ```www.stackoverflow | www.youtube.``` as a whole pattern due to '|'.join()? 

I used it before, but for this case,at least in my df,  it retained many rows containing stackoverflow or youtube.

Comment: @kingmakerking, so just "adapt" your `drop_list` correspondingly

Comment: @MaxU but already the drop_list contains the substrings that I want to match with the column values! In other words, in my example, I want to drop all rows containing URLS from stackoverflow or youtube. Sorry, I am unable to understand your hint :(

Comment: @kingmakerking, why can't you cut off all prefixes (`www`, etc.) and/or suffixes from `drop_list` elements?

Comment: In that case it will drop the rows containing a URL, say ```www,askmeanything.com/goodQuestionin_stackoverflow-question.html``` as well.

Comment: @kingmakerking, please post a __reproducible__ and desired data sets. This will help to avoid `Your suggestion does not work in that case!` situations...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136618/discussion-between-kingmakerking-and-maxu).

Comment: @MaxU https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/anonymous/74618ab59d2ab6f08a4dfa391894d50b and updated the questions. I hope it is clear now!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re

drp = [re.sub(r'www\.|\.$|\.com', '', x) for x in to_drop]
df[~df.col1.str.extract(r'http[s]*://([^/]*).*', expand=False)
  .str.contains('|'.join(drp))]
```

yields:

```
                                                                       col1
2  https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstart.html#create-a-textblob
3                                   https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/
4                          https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/stackoverflow
5                                https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/youtube
```

Explanation:

```
In [38]: drp
Out[38]: ['stackoverflow', 'youtube']

In [41]: df.col1.str.extract(r'http[s]*://([^/]*).*', expand=False)
Out[41]:
0          stackoverflow.com
1          stackoverflow.com
2    textblob.readthedocs.io
3    textblob.readthedocs.io
4    textblob.readthedocs.io
5    textblob.readthedocs.io
6            www.youtube.com
7            www.youtube.com
8            www.youtube.com
Name: col1, dtype: object

In [42]: df.col1.str.extract(r'http[s]*://([^/]*).*', expand=False).str.contains('|'.join(drp))
Out[42]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
7     True
8     True
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```