# Python/Pandas: Drop (not filter!) rows from data frame on string match from list

Tags: python, pandas

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663426/python-pandas-drop-rows-from-data-frame-on-string-match-from-list)  contains information on how to filter out rows. However, I want to know how to delete, not filter, rows from a data frame based on a string match from a list.

What's the fastest way to do this?

Edit: here's an example using the dataset provided in another thread.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
>>> df.head()

  fName   lName                    email   title
0  John   Smith         jsmith@gmail.com     CEO
1   Joe   Schmo      jschmo@business.com  Bagger
2  Some  Person  some.person@hotmail.com   Clerk
```

One solution given involves filtering out some rows as follows:

```
In [6]: to_drop = ['Clerk', 'Bagger']
        df[~df['title'].isin(to_drop)]

Out[6]:

  fName  lName             email title
0  John  Smith  jsmith@gmail.com   CEO
```

This work, but the data frame still contains those rows that I want to permanently delete:

```
In [7]: df.head()

Out[7]:

  fName   lName                    email   title
0  John   Smith         jsmith@gmail.com     CEO
1   Joe   Schmo      jschmo@business.com  Bagger
2  Some  Person  some.person@hotmail.com   Clerk
```

Comment: Well, you just assign the output of the filtering to a new DataFrame.

Comment: Or use [`df.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) on with `inplace=True`...

Comment: Could you provide an input and a desired output so that we can test on your issue?

Comment: @ysearka. Good idea. See my edit above.

Comment: just assign a new variable to your filter and `reset_index` if you do not care about your index: `new_df = df[~df['title'].isin(to_drop)]`

Comment: @mattmilten. This was my first instinct. I tried it and it didn't work initially. I have since tried again and it does work. Not sure why it didn't work for me the first time. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly figure this one out. Apologies for the seemingly naive question, but hope it helps out other Python newbies like myself.

The solution, as raised by @mattmilten, is to simply assign the output of the filtering to the same or a new data frame. That is,

```
In [3]: to_drop = ['Clerk', 'Bagger']
        df = df[~df['title'].isin(to_drop)]
        df

Out[3]:
        fName   lName      email          title
      0  John   Smith  jsmith@gmail.com     CEO
```