# Sum up values in a column using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I have a dataframe where one column has a list of zipcodes and the other has property values corresponding to the zipcode. I want to sum up the property values in each row according to the appropriate zipcode.

So, for example:

```
zip  value
2210 $5,000
2130 $3,000
2210 $2,100
2345 $1,000
```

I would then add up the values

```
$5,000 + $2,100  = $7,100
```

and reap the total property value of for zipcode 2210 as $7,100.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
df
    zip  value
0  2210   5000
1  2130   3000
2  2210   2100
3  2345   1000

df2 = df.groupby(['zip'])['value'].sum()

df2 
zip    value
2130    3000
2210    7100
2345    1000
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

You can read more about it [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

Also you will need to remove the $ sign in the column values. For that you can use something along the lines of the following while reading the dataframe initially:

```
df = pd.read_csv('zip_value.csv', header=0,names=headers,converters={'value': lambda x: float(x.replace('$',''))})
```

Edit: Changed the code according to comment.
To reset the index after groupby use:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['zip'])['value'].sum().reset_index()
```

Then to remove a particular column with zip value ,say, 2135 , you need

```
df3 = df2[df2['zip']!= 2135]
```

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question. What if I want to delete specific zip codes and their corresponding values (after summing up everything)?

Comment: You can use `df3 = df2[df2['zip'] != value_not_needed]` where value_not_needed is the zip code you don't want

Comment: Sorry I am a bit confused. Let's say I want zip 2130 and its value gone. How do I indicate so with the code you wrote above?

Comment: `df3 = df2[df2.index != 2130]`

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much for your help! Very new to pandas

Comment: I'm sorry. I hope you don't mind me asking one more question. I want to get rid of multiple zip codes. So I think I should use a formula. How do I go about with that?

Comment: `df3 = df2[ (df2.index != 2130) | (df2.index != 2345) ]` removes all rows where zip equals either 2130 or 2345. You can check it out in the below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29017525/deleting-rows-based-on-multiple-conditions-python-pandas