# Pandas filter or delete rows multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe `boroughCounts` with these sample values:

```
    From    To          Count
9   None    Manhattan   302
10  Bronx   Bronx       51
11  Bronx   Manhattan   244
12  None    Brooklyn    8
13  Bronx   Queens      100
14  None    None        67
```

Trying to filter out `None` values in "From" and "To" columns using this approach as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29017525/deleting-rows-based-on-multiple-conditions-python-pandas) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978550/pandas-filtering-multiple-conditions):

```
boroughCounts = boroughCounts[(boroughCounts.From != None) & (boroughCounts.To != None)]

boroughCounts = boroughCounts[(boroughCounts["From"] != None) & (boroughCounts["To"] != None)]
```

But it doesn't work, and all values remained as is.
Am I using it wrong, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: what does boroughCounts.info() return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, because None is a string and you need to replace that string with NaN:

```
df_out = boroughCounts.replace('None', np.nan).dropna()
df_out
```

Output:

```
     From         To  Count
10  Bronx      Bronx     51
11  Bronx  Manhattan    244
13  Bronx     Queens    100
```

Or you could use boolean indexing by using "None":

```
boroughCounts[(boroughCounts.From != "None") & (boroughCounts.To != "None")]
```

Comment: using "None" worked, thanks @Scott, seems it was converted to string when imported from the RDD! not sure

Answer (score 1):

Inspect your dataframe to understand the types.

```
boroughCounts.dtypes
```

This will tell you that he To and From cols are type object. That could mean they are all strings or a combination of string and None type. Inspect one of your Nones.

```
type(boroughCounts.iloc[15].From)
```

This will show you if the None in the From column for row 15 is a string. If so, you need to change your query.

Comment: those hints were helpful